# Joda time library getdays giving wrong result

Tags: java, jodatime

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException{


    String string = "May 2, 2016";
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = format.parse(string);
    System.out.println(date);
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
    DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    Period p = new Period(dateTime, currentDate);
    System.out.println(p.getYears());
    System.out.println(p.getMonths());
    System.out.println(p.getDays());

}
```

}

Result for days is 1

expected considering today is june 10 2016 it should be 8

Comment: ohh so is it that I have always to show in years months weeks days?

Comment: @RC. please put your comment as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong here, you get 1 because 8 days is one week and one day. If you want to get 8 for the "day", you have to compute it back from the week part (i.e. week * 7 + day).

Answer (score 2):

To get what you expect you should use another `PeriodType`: `PeriodType.yearMonthDay()`.

```
Period p = new Period(dateTime, currentDate, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
```

Currently your code uses standard (default) `PeriodType`, which breaks the period into years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, millis.